# How can enabled WiFi save battery?

Tags: batteries, wireless, energy

My Lumia 535 claims, that leaving my WiFi connection turned on can save the battery.

How can that be true?

I'm a layman, if not ignorant to this area of expertise, but from what I was always told comes assumptions, that:

- WiFi uses separate antennae, not used by any other technology, so turning it on causes device to power up another antennae and thus consumes more energy,
- Turning any wireless technology (WiFi, GPS, GPRS), when there is no connection to the destination or signal strength is very weak, consumes even more energy.

Since mobile devices are quite often used outside building and in other kind of areas with no or very poor WiFi coverage, leaving WiFi turned on all the time should in my opinion drain the battery like a hell. What am I missing?

Note: *This question is general to WiFi or even general to wireless technology, so I assume, it can be asked here.*

Comment: it may help you : http://www.androidcentral.com/android-101-save-battery-keeping-wifi-alive

Comment: As that article says, wifi uses less power than 3G/4G, so when the phone decides to download updates and other shit (your facebook/mail/twitter app decides to push/pull data etc.), you want it to find the wifi on. And no, it's not a generally valid strategy to leave an antenna on. Only works here as the lesser of two evils.

Comment: This [answer](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3711/11237) provides some scientific sources on WiFi being more energy efficient than 3G.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It saves battery... sort of. Please note, that this answer is based on [this article](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-101-save-battery-keeping-wifi-alive).

Leaving it on is only good if you are connected to WiFi, as using WiFi is less power hungry than using 2/3/4G. So keeping WiFi on means that you use the less power hungry communication method. However, if you're sat in the middle of nowhere with the WiFi on, it will drain the extra power as you would expect.